# cannot understand syntax for this class declaration

Tags: java

I am a beginner in java and i do not understand the following code.

```
    public class FlexibleItemHolderExample<Model> extends AbstractSectionableItem<FlexibleItemHolderExample.ViewHolder, HeaderItem>
    implements IFilterable, IHolder<Model>
```

why are <> used and what does the above declaration mean?

Comment: They're [generic type parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) (and generic type arguments). I suggest working through some Java tutorials.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

Comment: Start [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).

Comment: Generics :

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

Answer (score 2):

[Java templates](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) are a way you can write code where the TYPE is treated like a variable.

For example - let's say you wanted to make your own kind of List but you were not sure what types you wanted in your list, or you were thinking you would need one List for String types, one for Integer types and one for Double types.

With Generics, you can make ONE class (List) with a generic and then simply inject those types in.

In fact, this is exactly how List and ArrayList work:

```
List<Integer> myIntList;
ArrayList<String> myStringList;
```

and they have only ONE implementation sitting behind them, rather than one for each type of list. The added power is that you can have a list of custom objects in your lists without having to re-write the List / ArrayList types.